Is there a way to run in Google Colaboratory from VS Code app client?
I want to run training in colab but from vs code app as client. I saw few posts that allow something similar from web interface using colabcode.
My question is can I run it from the app client instead of from web interface? If yes, please point me to some documentation or let me know the steps I should follow.
My guess is if colabcode instantiates code server in colab, there should be way to connect to that from the app.

Yes, you can run Google Colaboratory notebooks from VS Code using the jupyter extension or through the VS Code integration with Google Colab via the Google Colab API. This allows you to edit and run code in Colab from within your local VS Code environment.
